# Allowed group can't access a folder

Tags: linux, permissions, users, group, acl

I've a weird problem on my linux machine, I've multiple users, we can say u1, u2, u3... who all belong to a group G. I have a group folder in /home who belong to one of these user (we'll say u1), and I wanted to allow other G users to read, write and execute in this folder, so I changed the folder's group to G (the owner still is u1), and set rwx permissions for the owner, for the group (G) and 000 for others, but G users can't access the folder...
Why is that ? any ideas ?
Thanks !

Comment: Please provide details. Show us at least the output of `ls -l` for the directory in question and for */home/*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

follow this instruction:

**1)** make sure that all the users u1,u2,u3 are in the group G:

```
lid -g GroupName
```

the output must contain all susers.

**2)** set group woner of the directory "recursively":

```
chown -R u1:GroupName /home/u1
```

**Note:** if you don't set the group owner recursively, you won't be able to view inner files and directories.

**3)** set the permissions of group owner of the directory "recursively":

```
chmod -R g+rwx /home/u1
```

**Note:** if you don't set the group owner permissions recursively, the changes won't be applied for inner files and directories.

now if you type `ls -l /home/u1`, the output will be like this:

```
drwxrwx---. 16 u1  GroupName  4096 Jan  8  2015 u1
```

I hope you get your problem solved soon :)

Comment: **WARNING**: executing `chmod -R g+rwx /home/u1` makes **ALL FILES** inside directory `/home/u1` executable! THIS IS NOT SECURE